# Finding trace for the very big matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this problem from my friends, and I don't know how to solve it.

He wants to find te trace of very big matrix $A^3$, which $A$ is bigger than $30,000 \times 30,000$.

Every diagonal entries of $A$ is zero, and $A = B+B^t$ for some matrix $B$, and $A$ is symmetry matrix.

---

At first, I thought $A$ is nilpotent matrix, but it was not. Is there any general solution for finding trace of $A$?

Comment: trace is sum of diagonal elements,  A is symmetric matrix,but besides this if every diagonal entrie is zero,then trace is zero,is not it?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I just edited the problem

Comment: you know    i will show some code in matlab

Comment: it is business of programming software,i hope that my answer will help you